# karma configuration to disable headless chrome and use only terminal

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run Angular unit test. I want to configure karma.config file not to open headless chrome. Simply I want to see output in terminal alone.

I tried by commenting below code lines in **karma.config**....

```
reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false

reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
```

running test should not open headless chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are currently not using headless chrome. It is getting launched since your setting has `[Chrome]`

You need change the `browser` array value.

> Change `browsers: ['Chrome']` to `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']`

Answer (score 4):

> Full `karma.conf.js` file with the ability to run only in terminal
>   using ChromeHeadless

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: false,
    customLaunchers:{
      HeadlessChrome:{
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox'
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```